# Launch app at login in OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I need to add my application to the login items in the system preferences when then user presses a button.  I've seen other answers around Stack Overflow, but many of them rely on <10.8 or <10.10 and deprecated APIs like LSSharedFileServices.  Some of the answers refer to LSSharedFileServices, to which I can't find the documentation on Apple's website.

I did find [this](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) but it seems like that is vastly over-engineered.

Should I just give up on Cocoa and use a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you mentioned is a very good approach. It seemes over-engineered, but it is quite simple to implement. I used this idea myself and it is ok for the Mac App Store. You should give it a try, if you don't like it, you can still look for something else

Comment: Hi, sorry for my delayed response. I shall give that a try and report back here my results as I do want to target the App Store.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi. It’s taken me 5 years to report back but: this works